# First-Line Indent and Justified Text

Tags: latex, indentation, justify, ragged

I am trying to create a APA Style Document (following class), but with justified text.

```
\documentclass[stu,11pt,a4paper,helv,biblatex,floatsintext]{apa7}
```

The problem is if I use the following package, it removes all the first-line indentations.

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix it and add the apa style indentation even with justified text?

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.